# Django regroup many to many field

Tags: django, many-to-many

I'm having some trouble making this work on the template, wonder if I could get some help:

I have a table with plants in it, and the plant table has a many-to-many relationship with the category table. Such that a plant can be in one or more categories.
I'm using Django 1.5, here are the models:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    scientific_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
```

And the view:

```
class PlantListView(ListView):
    context_object_name='plant_list'
    template_name='plants/index.html'
    model = Plant

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all().order_by('category')
```

I've tried this:

```
{% regroup plant_list by category as category_list %}
<ul>
{% for category in category_list %}
    <li>{{ category.grouper }}
        <ul>
            {% for plant in plant_list.list %}
                <li>{{ plant.scientific_name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But all I get is:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1053bfb90>
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1053bfbd0>
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1053bfd50>
```

Of course, what I really want is:

- Annuals

  - Ageratum houstonianum
  - Abutilon hybridum
  - Acalypha hispida
- Bulbs Perennial

  - Ageratum houstonianum
  - Allium giganteum
  - Allium karataviense

... etc ...

Note that the same plant can exist in multiple categories, and should be listed in each.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try this: `{% regroup plant_list by category.category as category_list %}`. If I am not wrong, you could use `.` in template syntax.

Comment: That's not it. `category_list` == `[{u'list': [<Plant: Acidanthera bicolor>, <Plant: Achimenes>, <Plant: Acidanthera bicolor>], u'grouper': None}]`. grouper is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turned out it was easier (and probably better) to make a Dict of all the results, with category as the index.